# Direct2D Create SwapChain

Tags: direct2d

I am trying to program a Direct2D desktop app based on a Windows tutorial, but am having problems creating a SwapChain1.  In the code below everything gets initialized until the CreateSwapChainForHwnd. The pointer m_pDXGISwapChain1 stays NULL. All the pointers except pOutput are ComPtrs.

```
D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS options;
ZeroMemory(&options, sizeof(D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS));

HRESULT hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED,
                                __uuidof(ID2D1Factory1), &options, &m_pD2DFactory1);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    UINT creationFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] = { D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0 };
    hr = D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, 0, creationFlags,     
        featureLevels, ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels), D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &m_pD3DDevice, 
        &m_featureLevel, &m_pD3DDeviceContext);
}

if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    hr = m_pD3DDevice.As(&m_pDXGIDevice1);

if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    hr = m_pD2DFactory1->CreateDevice(m_pDXGIDevice1.Get(), &m_pD2DDevice);

if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    hr =  m_pD2DDevice->CreateDeviceContext(D2D1_DEVICE_CONTEXT_OPTIONS_NONE, &m_pD2DDeviceContext);

 if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    hr = m_pDXGIDevice1->GetAdapter(&m_pDXGIAdapter); 

 if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    hr = m_pDXGIAdapter->GetParent(IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pDXGIFactory2));

DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapChainDesc1 = {0};
swapChainDesc1.Width = 0; 
swapChainDesc1.Height = 0;
swapChainDesc1.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;      
swapChainDesc1.Stereo = false; 
swapChainDesc1.SampleDesc.Count = 1;   
swapChainDesc1.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
swapChainDesc1.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
swapChainDesc1.BufferCount = 2;   
swapChainDesc1.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_NONE;
swapChainDesc1.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL;
swapChainDesc1.AlphaMode = DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE;
swapChainDesc1.Flags = 0;

IDXGIOutput *pOutput;
m_pDXGIAdapter->EnumOutputs(0, &pOutput);

if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
   hr = m_pDXGIFactory2->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(
            static_cast<IUnknown*>(m_pD3DDevice.Get()), m_hwnd, &swapChainDesc1, 
            NULL, pOutput, &m_pDXGISwapChain1);

if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    hr = m_pDXGIDevice1->SetMaximumFrameLatency(1);

if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    hr = m_pDXGISwapChain1->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pDXGIBackBuffer));
```

Answer (score 2):

If all your pointers are `ComPtr`, then the call should look like this:

```
ComPtr<ID3D11Device> d3dDevice;
ComPtr<IDXGIFactory2> dxgiFactory;
```

// assuming d3dDevice and dxgiFactory are initialized correctly:

```
ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain1> swapChain;
dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(d3dDevice.Get(), hWnd, &swapChainDescription, nullptr, nullptr, swapChain.GetAddressOf())
```

As for your swap chain description, if you're making a non-Windows Store App, you should set

```
swapChainDescription.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH;
swapChainDescription.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
```

Both of those values are `0`, so you can leave them out.

Here is the complete swap chain description that I use:

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapChainDescription = {};
swapChainDescription.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
swapChainDescription.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
swapChainDescription.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
swapChainDescription.BufferCount = 2;
```

See this article for full a walkthrough of how to set up Direct2D 1.1 properly - including the CreateSwapChainForHwnd call: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198239.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Direct2D don't have SwapChain at user level, SwapChain is for Direct3D, I see some DirectX 11 code in your post, do you really want Direct2D? or Direct3D?

Comment: Yes, Direct2D 1.1 does have a SwapChain "at user level" and requires you to set it up and use it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198239.aspx

Comment: @d7samurai, to be exactly, that's DXGI, not Direct2D, stop your down voting now.

Comment: well, YOU stated that "SwapChain is for Direct3D", thereby disregarding the DXGI distinction yourself. So in the same simplified spirit, Direct2D (1.1) has a SwapChain "at user level" just as much as Direct3D has one. And, no, I didn't vote you down.

Comment: @d7samurai No, obviously you didn't know the history of swap chain, Direct3D 9 has the [swap chain interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and that's moved to [DXGI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Direct3D 10/11, but Direct2D never has such interface, never! and the link you post used DXGI to create the swap chain, that's not Direct2D stuff. You said Direct2D 1.1 does have a SwapChain, please give the link of that interface.

Comment: You are not getting it. Direct3D 11 does not have a SwapChain interface either, it is a DXGI interface there, too, just like with Direct2D 1.1. I said that JUST LIKE YOU SPEAK OF DIRECT3D AS IF IT HAS A SWAPCHAIN INTERFACE, IT IS VALID TO SPEAK OF DIRECT2D AS IF IT HAS (neither actually has the interface directly attached to their domain, but that is beside the point). The point here was that in your answer you talk like a SwapChain is not needed in Direct2D ("SwapChain is for Direct3D"), but it is! In exactly the same way it is needed in Direct3D. Direct2D is built on top of Direct3D.

Comment: @d7samurai Did you see my comments clearly? I didn't say Direct3D 11 have a swap chain interface, I said that was moved to DXGI since Direct3D 10/11.

Comment: `I said that JUST LIKE YOU SPEAK OF DIRECT3D AS IF IT HAS A SWAPCHAIN INTERFACE, IT IS VALID TO SPEAK OF DIRECT2D AS IF IT HAS`, I don't like the word `as if`, we need the truth, not as if. both Direct3D 9 and DXGI has the swap chain interface, that's not as if, that's the truth.

Comment: you said "direct2d don't have swapchain at user level". 'at user level'? what is that supposed to mean? that you don't have to deal with swapchains when using direct2d (because the swapchain is somehow hidden from the user or 'embedded' in direct2d)? that's wrong. you do. so when working with direct2d there are swapchains 'at user level' that you have to set up - EXACTLY LIKE WHEN WORKING WITH DIRECT3D. it does not matter whether the swapchain interface is part of direct2d (or direct3d) ITSELF - that's just a technicality, irrelevant to this question.

Comment: then you said that "swapchain is for direct3d" - which is ALSO false. it seems that you think (thought? because you must have realized your mistake by now) that you don't need to work with swapchains in direct2d, only in direct3d. but as i said, both direct3d and direct2d need swapchains - in the EXACT SAME WAY. and for the exact same reason - swapchains are simply a group of multibuffered render targets, necessary for performant gpu rendering. since direct2d is built on top of direct3d it has the same need for a swapchain as direct3d.

Comment: direct2d didn't even exist alongside direct3d 9, so i don't know why you even bring that old version of direct3d up here - nobody is talking about direct3d at all - just you! the OP has a question regarding direct2d, and you didn't understand why he was bringing swapchains into the picture - because you obviously didn't know that you have to work with swapchains in direct2d, too! THAT is the situation here, which got commented on (and downvoted - by someone ELSE). sheesh.

Comment: A swap chain can only be created by way of a `ID3D11Device`. Using a swapchain with direct2d requires some interop with direct3d